# How to access Azure table storage secondary storage in RA-GRS using NodeJs SDK

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

**Updated**
I tried the following but getting `This operation can only be executed against the primary storage location.` error:

```
     var azure = require('azure-storage');
const host = {
    primaryHost: `https://${primaryAccountName}.table.core.windows.net`,
    secondaryHost: `https://${primaryAccountName}-secondary.table.core.windows.net`
  };
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService(primaryAccountName, accessKey, host);

tableSvc.retrieveEntity(tableName, 'hometasks', '1', 
   { locationMode: locationMode.SECONDARY_ONLY }
    , function(error, result, response){
    if(error){
      console.log('Error on retrieveEntity!', error, result, response);
    } else {
      console.log('Entity retrieved', task.published._);
    }
  });
```

Isn't `retrieveEntity` a read operation? what are the read operations that could be executed against the secondary storage?

Comment: There's no separate access key for secondary endpoint of your storage account. Are you sure you're using correct access key?

Comment: First confirm that all of your endpoints and keys are correct by testing with Azure storage explorer.

Comment: I updated the question,  I needed to use the locationMode.

Comment: Can you re-edit your question and include how are you creating `tableSvc`?

Comment: I am not re-creating it, the table is already created and exists.@GauravMantri

Comment: No, I meant `tableSvc` variable.

Comment: Updated @GauravMantri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `requestLocationMode` option when retrieving entities and it should work fine. I tried with the following code:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
const primaryAccountName = 'accountname';
const accessKey = 'accountkey==';
const tableName = 'tablename';

const host = {
  primaryHost: `https://${primaryAccountName}.table.core.windows.net`,
  secondaryHost: `https://${primaryAccountName}-secondary.table.core.windows.net`
};

var tableSvc = azure.createTableService(primaryAccountName, accessKey, host);


tableSvc.retrieveEntity(tableName, '001', '002',
   { locationMode: azure.StorageUtilities.LocationMode.SECONDARY_ONLY,
      requestLocationMode: azure.StorageUtilities.LocationMode.SECONDARY_ONLY}
    , function(error, result, response){
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error on retrieveEntity!', error, result, response);
    } else {
      console.log('Entity retrieved', error, result, response);
    }
  });
```

This is the response I got (partial):

```
{
  isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {
    'odata.metadata': 'https://accountname-secondary.table.core.windows.net/$metadata#tablename/@Element',
    'odata.etag': `W/"datetime'2021-03-04T06%3A36%3A14.3452027Z'"`,
    PartitionKey: '001',
    RowKey: '002',
    Timestamp: '2021-03-04T06:36:14.3452027Z',
    DataKey: '{"id":"TEST_155397_0","type":"G"}'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but what is this `requestLocationMode`, why both  `requestLocationMode`and `locationMode ` should be set?